# Can't run Pandas in R via reticulate: lxml not found

Tags: pandas, rstudio, lxml, reticulate

I'm trying to scrape a wiki table in Python from within RStudio (in Rmarkdown) via `reticulate`. I can't manage to do it with R (tried `rvest` but the columns end up being misaligned and I can't figure out exactly why) which is why I'm using Python: I have a `r-reticulate` Conda env and installed `BeautifulSoup` and `requests`.

The code I've written runs flawlessly in my Jupyter notebook running the `r-reticulate` kernel.

However, when I try to run it in RStudio, I get an `ImportError` saying `lxml` was not found. Which can't be, because it *is* there as you can see at the bottom with `conda list` (and as evidenced by my working notebook).

Here is my full code:

````
```{r libraries, include=FALSE}
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv("r-reticulate", required = TRUE)
```

```{python results="hide"}
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

```{python}
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_lockdowns"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "wikitable"})
dfs = pd.read_html(str(table))               # this is the line that generates the error
df = dfs[0]
df.head(20)
```
````

This is the error output from the last chunk:

```
ImportError: lxml not found, please install it

Detailed traceback: 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1100, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only,
  File "C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 889, in _parse
    parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
  File "C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 846, in _parser_dispatch
    raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
```

The env name is truncated (`R-RETI~1`) but I don't have any other env starting with this name, so I'm sure that it is the correct env. `py_config()` also shows that it is the correct env being used. I don't understand what is going on, or which component is not behaving correctly (is it coming from reticulate?)...

```
python:         C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/python37.dll
pythonhome:     C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.7.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 19 2021, 15:37:01) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.20.1

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

Output of `conda list`:

```
(r-reticulate) C:\[...]>conda list

# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\r-reticulate:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.9.3              pyhb0f4dca_0    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37hcc03f2d_1001    conda-forge
bs4                       4.9.3                         0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.12.5            h5b45459_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.12.5        py37h03978a9_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.5           py37hd8e9650_0    conda-forge
chardet                   4.0.0            py37h03978a9_1    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
cryptography              3.4.6            py37h20c650d_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_2    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h546665d_1    conda-forge
icu                       68.1                 h0e60522_0    conda-forge
idna                      2.10               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2020.3             h57928b3_311    conda-forge
ipykernel                 5.5.0            py37heaed05f_1    conda-forge
ipython                   7.21.0           py37heaed05f_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.0           py37h03978a9_2    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.12             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py37h03978a9_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py37h8c56517_1    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.12                 h2a16943_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libclang                  11.1.0          default_h5c34c98_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 he774522_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h1d00b33_2    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h8d14728_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.2.0                hc10be44_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.10               hf5bbc77_3    conda-forge
libxslt                   1.1.33               h65864e5_2    conda-forge
lxml                      4.6.2            py37hd07aab1_1    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.3.4            py37h03978a9_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.3.4            py37h3379fd5_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2020.4             hb70f87d_311    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    conda-forge
numpy                     1.20.1           py37hd20adf4_0    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46               pyh9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1j               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.2.3            py37h08fd248_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    8.1.2            py37h96663a1_0    conda-forge
pip                       21.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.17             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pygments                  2.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.12.3           py37h03978a9_7    conda-forge
pyqt-impl                 5.12.3           py37hf2a7229_7    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 4.19.18          py37hf2a7229_7    conda-forge
pyqtchart                 5.12             py37hf2a7229_7    conda-forge
pyqtwebengine             5.12.1           py37hf2a7229_7    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py37h03978a9_3    conda-forge
python                    3.7.10          h7840368_100_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pywin32                   300              py37hcc03f2d_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     22.0.3           py37hcce574b_1    conda-forge
qt                        5.12.9               h5909a2a_4    conda-forge
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.6.0            py37h6db1a17_0    conda-forge
seaborn                   0.11.1               hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
seaborn-base              0.11.1             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
setuptools                49.6.0           py37h03978a9_3    conda-forge
six                       1.15.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
soupsieve                 2.0.1                      py_1    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.34.0               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.12.2           py37hda49f71_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
tornado                   6.1              py37hcc03f2d_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.0.5                      py_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.2                 hb210afc_4    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.28.29325          h5e1d092_4    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py37h03978a9_2    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2             py37h03978a9_1006    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_1    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h62dcd97_1010    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.9                h6255e5f_0    conda-forge
```

EDIT: For reasons unknown and without doing anything, it now works. The system probably needed one more reboot I guess...

Comment: Unrelated but would you mind explaining why are you writing *and* running Python code in R studio?

Comment: do you have more than 1 python version installed? The problem is not beautifulsoup but that pandas uses lxml under the hood.

Comment: @QHarr You're right, I found that out while looking for the specific line that produced the error but didn't think that I could edit the title. Turns out I can :) As for python versions, yes I have multiple Conda environments. I thought I checked that it was the specified one that is being used, but there's obviously a problem somewhere, so if you have other ways of checking, I'm all ears.

Comment: @baduker I already have a full R project. Up until now I was "hand-scraping" some of the data (lockdown dates) via a web tool to generate a csv, that I then import and clean with R. But this is not practical, as every time I knit the Rmarkdown, I need to manually update this data. As stated in my post, I failed at correctly importing the data with rvest, and since RStudio now allows python and R to cohabitate, I thought this would be the ideal solution (because my python solution works). But I'm stuck...

Comment: Side note: rvest failed due to "merged cells". You would need to loop all table rows and columns and account for the rowspan/colspan values to reconstitute the table as it appears on the page. It's a faff and I can understand why you prefer to use pandas here. I'm honestly surprised there isn't a popular R package to handle this situation given how common it is.